# Php picture name pattern

Tags: php

Just wondering if one could help

I am using a script which requires image filenames to be in this format :

```
$config_pictureNamePattern = '%d%m%Y%H%i
```

and files it currently is looking for is in this format, day,month,year, hour  :

```
image-0110-2017-0014.jpg
```

However, my camera is only able to send in this format :

```
20220218150001.jpg
```

How can i fix this ?

Matt

Comment: Can you explain what those numbers represent? And which one, if any, relates to `'%d%m%Y%H%i` and how?

Comment: Images in a folder. So the code i am using requires images to be in that format but my IP camera is sending different format - date

Comment: Sorry, you're keeping things way to vague. Should we guess? For instance `20220218150001.jpg` is a file from year 2022? February? The 18th? At 15:00:01 hour? Why do you let us guess these things? I have no idea what the numbers in `image-0110-2017-0014.jpg` stand for or how they relate to `'%d%m%Y%H%i`, or not.

Comment: As you've imagined i am a newbie! Sorry :(

Comment: image-0110-2017-0114.jpg is related to %d%m%Y%H%i

Comment: I understand that, but often things that newbies find difficult are difficult for us too. We're not clairvoyant.  Try to edit your question, and add what you know about these formats. And if possible, be clear about what you want to do with them.

Comment: I recognize a string like `%d%m%Y%H%i`. It specifies date elements. There are several formats for this however: [datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) and [others](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). I can't see a relation with `image-0110-2017-0114.jpg`.

Comment: Details are needed to really answer. Are you asking how to change the expected format? Or, do you want to rename your file?

Answer (score 1):

Details are needed to really answer. Are you asking how to change the expected format? Seems a good approach

Or, do you want to rename your file? If the later, then it sounds like you are asking about basic string manipulation. Here is an approach using two string functions.

```
<?php

$raw = '20220218150001.jpg';

$year = substr($raw, 0, 4);
$month = substr($raw, 4, 2);
$day = substr($raw, 6, 2);
$pictureNumber = substr($raw, 8, 10-strpos($raw, '.'));

$converted = "image-{$day}{$month}-{$year}-{$pictureNumber}.jpg";

echo $converted;
```

If you need time parts and they are not present in the filenmame you could leverage filesystem, pull from EXIF, or make it up.

Seeing your comment. You can see how that date format is used here: https://github.com/NikoleiTesla/tilacam/blob/master/php/picture.php in the `parseName()` function. Not super complicated. I'd play around with it and learn if you're interested. Best way.

Really about just these lines...

```
<?php
$config_pictureNamePattern = '%d%m%Y%H%i';
$filename = 'image-0110-2017-1629.jpg';

//Above is 'passed in'

//fix formatting by removing %'s
$config_pictureNamePattern = str_replace('%','',$config_pictureNamePattern);

//get just the number part of the file name.
$filename = basename($filename);
$res = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $filename);

//parse that string for a DateTime.
$dateTime = date_create_from_format($config_pictureNamePattern, $res);

$formatedDateTime = date_format($dateTime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

var_dump($formatedDateTime);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am now looking into that file.

Comment: Absolutely no clue of what i am doing :/

Comment: That's how it starts! Main thing there is really use of [date_create_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). That code, as name suggests, parses the file name and then sets class properties based on those dates and times. Just add `die(var_dump($variable))` every line and "step" through it.